# move_uploaded_file error 6 php

Tags: php, file-upload

Attempting to move an uploaded file so that it is saved in the directory, it fails.  I use `echo ($_FILES['company_logo'] ['error']);` to get the error number.  The only place I could find with error numbers for this was http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/php/article.php/3472561/PHP-Tutorial-Error-Handling.htm .  However, their list only goes up to 4 and I am getting the error number 6.  Does anyone know what this error stands for?  Here is my code:

```
$allowed_filetypes = array('.jpg','.jpeg','.gif','.bmp','.png'); // These will be the types of file that will pass the validation.
$max_filesize = 524288; // Maximum filesize in BYTES (currently 0.5MB).
$upload_path = '../images/companies/'; // The place the files will be uploaded to (currently a 'files' directory).

if($_FILES['company_logo']['name'] != "") {
    if($row['image'] != ''){
        unlink("../".$row['image']);
    }

    $filename = $_FILES['company_logo']['name']; // Get the name of the file (including file extension).               
    $ext = substr($filename, strpos($filename,'.'), strlen($filename)-1); // Get the extension from the filename.
    $ext = strtolower($ext);
    // Check if the filetype is allowed, if not DIE and inform the user.
    if(!in_array($ext,$allowed_filetypes))
        die('The file you attempted to upload is not allowed.');

    // Now check the filesize, if it is too large then DIE and inform the user.
    if(filesize($_FILES['company_logo']['tmp_name']) > $max_filesize)
        die('The file you attempted to upload is too large.');

    // Check if we can upload to the specified path, if not DIE and inform the user.
    if(!is_writable($upload_path))
        die('You cannot upload to the specified directory, please CHMOD it to 777.');

      // Upload the file to your specified path.
    $ran = rand();
    $filename = $ran.$ext;
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['company_logo']['tmp_name'],$upload_path.$filename)){  // This is where it fails
           $file = $upload_path.$filename;

           $result = mysql_query("UPDATE Companies SET image = 'images/companies/$filename' WHERE id = '$id';");                                                        

           if($result)
              $_SESSION['message'] .= "<p class='copy' style='color:red;'>Your image upload was successful.</p>"; // It worked.
           else
              $_SESSION['message'] .= "<p class='copy' style='color:red;'>Unable to upload image(s).</p>";
    }else{
           $_SESSION['message'] .= "<p class='copy' style='color:red;'>Unable to upload image(s).</p>";
           echo ($_FILES['company_logo'] ['error']);
            die();
    }
}
```

As you can see, I do check for an actual file being uploaded, if the file extension is in a list of file types allowed, if the file exceeds the max file size, and whether the path is even writable.  So I don't believe it is any of those things, but I'm not certain.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php) knows 99,99% answers.

> **UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR**
>
> Value: 6; Missing a temporary folder. Introduced in PHP 4.3.10 and
>   PHP 5.0.3.

Comment: Thanks.  I was actually there, but didn't see a list.

Comment: so, given that this is the answer, how to go about fixing it?

Comment: By setting correct, writable path in php.ini: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: [here is](http://us.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php) a list of all file upload errors which can occurs.

Your error is:

> Value: 6; Missing a temporary folder. Introduced in PHP 4.3.10 and PHP 5.0.3.

Comment: Thanks.  Don't know why I couldn't find that when searching.  dev-null-dweller answered about 40 seconds previous, though, so I'm going to accept theirs as the answer.

Comment: I saw his answer after posting mine, but it's quite the same :) Do as you feel

Comment: Yeah, he probably posted his as you wrote yours.  I'm just going off the times it says it was posted is all.