# upload file to web server error 6 php

Tags: php, file-upload, upload, php-ini

I am trying to upload a file from a php form.It wont work on linux server. I want it to move it to a subdir '/uploads' from where the file is.

I get the below error when executing the page by `echo` the `$_FILES["file_upload"]['error'];` to get the error number.

**It returns :**

```
Upload failed with error code 6
```

Does anyone know what this error stands for?

**Form Code :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select File to upload:
    <input type="file" name="file_upload" id="file_upload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**upload.php :**

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        if($_FILES['file_upload']['name'] != "" )
    {
            $target_dir = "uploads/";
            $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file_upload"]["name"]);
            $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            $uploadOk = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        die("No file specified!");
    }

    // Check if file already exists
    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
        echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    // Check file size
    if ($_FILES["file_upload"]["size"] > 500000) {
        echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    // Allow certain file formats
    if($imageFileType != "txt" && $imageFileType != "xls" && $imageFileType != "xlsx")
     {
        echo "Sorry, only TXT, XLS, XLSX files are allowed.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    if ($_FILES["file_upload"]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
       die("Upload failed with error code " . $_FILES['file_upload']['error']);
    }
    // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file_upload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["file_upload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        } else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
    }
    }
    ?>
```

I already search for this problem and find the solution [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719244/move-uploaded-file-error-6-php). But not undestand properly.
I also given full permission **777** to `/uploads` folder.
Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You should search first for the problem.Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719244/move-uploaded-file-error-6-php

Comment: @sgt, I already search for the problem but not understand the solution given by this post.

Comment: it is there.Probably you dont know the settings then. Then ask the proper question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR

Value: 6; Missing a temporary folder. Introduced in PHP 5.0.3.
```

http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Fix your settings..

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by using "setenforce 0" to enter permissive mode on SELinux;

```
[root@localhost tequila]# setenforce 0
```

Comment: This was the fix for CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908. sys_temp_dir in php.ini was ignored without this. Upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

> In case if file upload working previously fine and /tmp folder is in use for uploading files then just restart apache services to fix this problem:

In ubuntu you can use following command to restart apache services :

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit your php.ini file , and update the below changes and restart apache or iis

like below -

error_log = "C:\Windows\new_folder\php-5.6.1_errors.log"

upload_tmp_dir = "C:\Windows\new_folder"

Answer (score 0):

**Plesk setup with PHP 5.4**

For me, it was `upload_tmp_dir` having no value. I tried to set `/tmp` and that too didn't work even if it had 777/1777 permission.

So, I created a new directory `tmp` in the folder which was mentioned in the value `open_basedir` of php.ini. For me it was `/var/www/vhosts/xxxxxx.xxx/` and then I set it up as `upload_tmp_dir='/var/www/vhosts/xxxxxx.xxx/tmp'`.

I used Plesk dashboard to set PHP Configuration -> `Additional Directives`.

And it worked.

Happy coding.